# Debugging Ajax/XmlHttpRequests using Xdebug on Sublime

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, xdebug, sublimetext

What settings should I use for debugging PHP files called by XmlHttpRequests?  My client is coded in Elm, so it is a single page application (SPA) invoking a series of PHP files.  When I am debugging, I would like to see the cursor at the first line of the PHP file in Sublime whenever that file is invoked, and then be able to step through it, or let it run onto a breakpoint, or the end.

I have Xdebug installed and the Xdebug Client Plug-in installed in Sublime.  Currently, my Sublime project file looks like this:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "follow_symlinks": true,
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "xdebug": {
            "url": "http://localhost/GDAS/GDASExhibitors"
        }
    }

}
```

The xdebug section in php.ini looks like this:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930/xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_port=9000
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
```

Within Sublime, I am using the default Xdebug settings.  I can get it to break at breakpoints in certain files, but not others.  I think this may be something to do with multiple "sessions".

Comment: I don't think sublime supports multiple debugging sessions at the same time. You can find out what Xdebug is trying to do by also setting `xdebug.log=/path/to/xdebug.log` and `xdebug.log_level=11`. It will show each attempt to connect to the debugger, and whether it succeeded (and a lot more).

Comment: This issue arose only because of my misunderstanding of what a debugging session is.  There is one session per PHP file, not one single session from the time you launch the browser.  The multiple debugging sessions I can live without, but I had misunderstood the effect of `xdebug.start_with_request=yes`, which I have now added to php.ini.